# Having a property of a typescript class depend on two others, how to proceed?

Tags: angular, typescript

Im having a typescript class in angular with three properties. This is running in an angular web-application. The first two are able to change independently via [(ngModel)]. I want the last property to simply be the sum of the previous two, but i also need it to be changed whenever either of the other two are changed.

My first instinct tells me to implement it either as an observable or a behavioursubject. But my gut-instinct tells me this is way overkill, and theres a simpler way to do this.

I want this third property to be accessible by interpolation

```
export class Character {
  initialStat: number;
  advancementStat: number;
  totalStat: ???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do it in the ts file you could do

```
export class Character {
  initialStat: number;
  advancementStat: number;
  get totalStat() {
      return this.initialStat + this.advancementStat;
  }
}
```